# Apparently Gaussian random variable but with different moments

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

I have a complex random variable, $z$, which I am sampling numerically.

On the one hand, the real and imaginary parts seem to be independent and well described by Gaussian distributions $N(1,\sigma)$ and $N(0,\sigma)$, respectively.

On the other hand, for such a Gaussian distribution the moments should all be unit, $\langle z^n\rangle=1$. And this is definitely **not** the case for my variable.

(I can show analyticaly and verify numericaly that $\langle z\rangle=1$, $\langle z^2\rangle=4$, $\langle z^3\rangle=18$)

How is this possible?

I guess the question is: can I say for sure, based on the moments being different, that the distribution is not Gaussian, even though visually it is incredibly close to Gaussian?

Comment: Depending on what $\sigma$ is, there's no reason for the moments of a Gaussian to all be $1$. That would only be for a standard normal distribution, with mean $0$ and variance $1$.

Comment: @MattSamuel Please notice that the variable is complex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it is easy to show that your assertion is correct:  For $Z = X+Yi$ where $X \sim \operatorname{Normal}(1, \sigma^2)$ and $Y \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,\sigma^2)$ are independent, $$M_Z(t) = M_X(t) \varphi_Y(t) = e^{t + \sigma^2 t^2/2} e^{-\sigma^2 t^2/2} = e^t,$$ where $M$ and $\varphi$ are the moment-generating and characteristic functions, respectively.  Consequently for each positive integer $k$, $$\operatorname{E}[Z^k] = \left[\frac{d^k M_Z}{dt^k} \right]_{t=0} = e^0 = 1.$$
As to why your data appear to be well-modeled by this distribution yet do not have moments that fit, I invite you to perform a simple empirical exercise to help you understand one of a number of possible explanations:  generate a large number, say $n = 10^6$ realizations of $X$ and $Y$ from the aforementioned distributions; choose a modest but not-too-small $\sigma$; e.g., $\sigma = 5$.  Compute $Z$, $Z^2$, $Z^4$, and $Z^6$, and then compute their sample means.  I used the following in *Mathematica*:

```
Mean[{#, #^2, #^4, #^6} & /@ (RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[1, 5], 10^6] 
     + I RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 5], 10^6])]
```

And I got the output

$$\{0.997745 - 0.00691614 i,  0.927777 - 0.0774919 i, 
 9.00441 + 1.46326 i, -527.4 + 2161.76 i \}.$$

Why do you think this is happening?  Even for a very large $n$, the higher order moments seem to not behave well in the sense that the asymptotic convergence is poor.  I leave question this as an exercise for the reader, but I would suggest considering the variance of the sample $k^{\rm th}$ moment estimator.